# Apply display settings for a folder recursively

Tags: finder, icon, settings

### Question

When I change the display settings in Finder, it is only applied for the current folder that I'm in.

**I want to apply a display settings for all (sub-)folders in** `~/Pictures`.

Since it's only for `~/Pictures`, using the option 'Use as Defaults' will not help me. How can I do this?

[image]

### Solution (thanks to @hobs)

The following tutorial uses an automator workflow. The workflow has to be run again when you add a new subdirectory to `~/Pictures`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question fits with this thread and my answer to it:
[System-wide finder view preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/system-wide-finder-view-preferences/11962#11962)

Short answer, it isnt that easy, but if you are willing do to some work you can make it happen.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. However, once I added new folders, the settings were not inherited. But then you can save the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Laborious but should do what you want: open each subfolder, set the display settings you want to use, then check “Always open in * view” at the top of the display settings inspector panel. This will save all the defaults.